# Nlog console target not working mono?

Tags: mono, nlog

I have a very simple console app. I've added Nlog with the console target, but I can't get it to work when running in mono (on windows and ubuntu). I've tried the file target and it works.
 What am I missing?

**Code**

```
class Program
{
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type t = Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime");
        if (t != null)
            Console.WriteLine("You are running with the Mono VM");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("You are running something else");

        Console.WriteLine("Lets go Mono");
        logger.Trace("Sample trace message");
        logger.Debug("Sample debug message");
        logger.Info("Sample informational message");
        logger.Warn("Sample warning message");
        logger.Error("Sample error message");
        logger.Fatal("Sample fatal error message");
    }
}
```

**Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <targets async="true">
    <target name="console" xsi:type="Console"/>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="console" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

**Nlog package**

```
 <package id="NLog" version="4.3.10" targetFramework="net452" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You code and config looks valid.

There is an issue with the Console target on Mono with NLog 4.3.10, [which will be fixed in 4.3.11](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1704). The detection if the Console is available doesn't work correctly as `Environment.UserInteractive` isn't working on Mono

For now set `detectConsoleAvailable="false"` for Mono, so:

```xml
<target name="console" xsi:type="Console" detectConsoleAvailable="false"/>
```

Comment: Works as expected now. About to start my first mono project - glad to have nlog available, thanks